# How to manage rate limiting with twitter in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, rate, rate-limiting

I have been working with the twitter api. I am trying to log some tweets from a group of accounts. There are 250 accounts that I am tracking. This of course exceeds the rate limit. The code for the data collection is below:

```
docs.forEach(function (doc) {
    client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {
        screen_name: doc.screen_name,
        limit: 20
    }, function (error, tweets, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            if (error.code == 88) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        } else {
            tweets.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b.retweet_count - a.retweet_count
            });
            var top = tweets.slice(0, 3);
            col_tweets.insert(top, {
                w: 1
            }, function (err, result) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("error while logging");
                } else {
                    console.log("logged: " + doc.screen_name);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

As you can see the program logs some tweets from these accounts. I am running into rate limiting errors. I would like to find a solution to time the requests so I dont run into these errors. As I see it there are two problems: a) I eventually run out of requests (the obvious problem) b) I believe the speed at which I make the requests is to fast resulting in sporadic rate limit exceeded problem i.e. I will have 10 successful requests and then a code: 88 error then seven good ones and so on until I run out of calls. How is this sort of problem usually handled? If theres a simple solution that I can see in code I appreciate it but otherwise I'd like to hear any suggestsions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to solve this problem, but I would suggest that you create a work queue for the data for all the requests that you want to make (e.g. an array of data objects).

Then, you can run items off the end of the queue on a timer such that you are never making requests more than once every N seconds and perhaps you never have more than M requests in flight at once.  If the rate limits are not published, then you may have to do some experimentation to see what rate you are consistently allowed to fire requests (by adjusting your timer time) without triggering any limiting.